# Laravel master page not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am working on my master page which is currently not working. In browser it returns:

> @layout('master') and not key as specified.

code in routes.php

```
    Route::get('/', function() 
    {    
        return View::make('index');    
    });
```

code in view: index.blade.php

```
 @layout('master')
    @section('container')
    <h1> Hey </h1>
    @endsection
```

code in view: master.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
@yield('container')
```

Comment: Found the problem, edit from layout to extends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use  `@extends('master')` in L4 and have it right at the top of your file.

I mean RIGHT at the top, line 1, with no white space around it. This use to be a problem in L3, not sure if it also is the case for L4.

Answer (score 1):

replace @layout with @extends

refer http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating for Using A Blade Layout